# android studio - gradle executing tasks hangs on generateDebugSources

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have created a new android application through the wizard and select the navigation drawer project. As soon as I tried to build the project the execution task hangs at :app:mergeDebugResources in the Gradle console. I have let it sit for half hour and then tried to exit android studio causing it to hang on "stopping execution tasks". I have to go to task manager and "end task" android studio. Now every time I load my project (start android studio), execution task hangs from the start. Since it hangs, i am unable to debug or move any further in development. Attached is a picture of what I see every time I start android studio and load/create a new project.

Has anyone else encountered this problem? Is there something I should check to resolve this?

here is a link to the screenshot that im seeing every time i load android studio

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUFmp.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i had used an older version of Android Studio a while back and the folder was located somewhere else. I delete the traces of all android studio versions and then downloaded the latest one. This is what worked for me.